# why methods inside parent constructor actually invoke child method

Tags: java, methods, constructor, polymorphism

```
 class Glyph {
      void draw() {
        System.out.println("glyph.draw()");
      }

    Glyph() {
        System.out.println("glyph() before draw");
        draw();
        System.out.println("glyph() after draw");
    }
 }

 class RoundGlyph extends Glyph {
    private int radius = 1;

    RoundGlyph(int r) {
        radius = r;
        System.out.println("roundGlyph.RoundGlyph:" + radius);
    }

    @Override
    void draw() {
        System.out.println("roundGlyph.draw:" + radius);
    }
}

public class PolyConstructors {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      new RoundGlyph(3);
    } 
}
```

the output is :

```
glyph() before draw
**roundGlyph.draw:0**
glyph() after draw
roundGlyph.RoundGlyph:3
```

I am confused about the second result,why the code `draw()` in the parent class constructor,actually invoke the child draw method other than parent draw method?

Comment: This is how inheritancy work

Comment: @MadProgrammer except its not how inheritance works in C++.

Comment: @MichaelAnderson Well when the OP post a question about C++, I'll be sure to remember it ;)

Comment: If you create object of `Glyph` (`new Glyph()`) then its `Glyph.draw()` method will be called. And if you create object of `RoundGlyph` then its `RoundGlyph.draw()` method will be called.

Comment: so every time when I initialize `RoundGlyph` object with `new RoundGlyph() `,whether It will initialize `Glyph` object or not

Comment: @side See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7173019/why-is-constructor-of-super-class-invoked-when-we-declare-the-object-of-sub-clas) for more information on that.

Answer (score 2):

So that `draw()` call is calling `this.draw()` where `this` is your instantiated object.

In this case, `this` refers to an object of type `RoundGlyph` which has overridden the `Draw()` method. In the context of a `RoundGlyph` object, there is no `Draw` method that prints `"glyph.draw()"` That's gone.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because of overriding.

What is overriding ?

> Method overriding, in object oriented programming, is a language feature that allows a subclass or child class to provide a specific implementation of a method that is already provided by one of its superclasses or parent classes. The implementation in the subclass overrides (replaces) the implementation in the superclass by providing a method that has same name, same parameters or signature, and same return type as the method in the parent class.

How is it decided which method will be executed ?

> The version of a method that is executed will be determined by the object that is used to invoke it.

Notice that the **object** decides which method is called.

---

In your case an object of `RoundGlyph` is used when `draw()` is called. Since the class `RoundGlyph` overrides the `draw` function, the `draw` inside `RoundGlyph` is invoked.

For further reading see [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7173019/why-is-constructor-of-super-class-invoked-when-we-declare-the-object-of-sub-clas)

Comment: so every time when I initialize `RoundGlyph ` object with `new RoundGlyph() `,It is also  initialize  `Glyph ` object too.

Comment: @side Yes, when a derived class object is constructed, the base class is also constructed. Read more about inheritance [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)

Comment: @side See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7173019/why-is-constructor-of-super-class-invoked-when-we-declare-the-object-of-sub-clas) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you create object of sub-class default constructor of parent call is called and then the sub-class constructor. And method calls are determined at runtime and it depends on the object being created.

If you create object of `Glyph` (`new Glyph()`) then its `Glyph.draw()` method will be called. And if you create object of `RoundGlyph` then its `RoundGlyph.draw()` method will be called.

If you want to call parent class method from child class overridden method then you will have to explicitly call (using [`super`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html) keyword) it from child class method.

```
@Override
void draw() {
    super.draw();
    System.out.println("roundGlyph.draw:" + radius);
}
```

For more detailed explanation and examples refer [inheritance documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html).

Comment: so every time when I initialize RoundGlyph object with new RoundGlyph() ,whether It will initialize Glyph object or not

Comment: You can think it this way, inheritance is inheriting properties and method of super class as well as adding some new functionality. You can see how your super class default constructor is called when you initialized you sub class object.

Comment: @side, I have added documentation link for **inheritance** and **super** keyword.